# jQuery: How can I check if an element was added dynamically or not?

Tags: jquery, events

I have a little tooltip. In some places it's added dynamically onto the page. In others it exists from the start.

Because something like `$("mytooltip").mouseover(...)` would not work for elements that are added dynamically I have to use something like `$("body").on("mouseover, ".mytooltip", function(){...})`

I'm worried however that with the second solution it will try to fire a function each time I move the mouse on `body` which is very inefficient (right?).

I'm thinking perhaps I could fire some kind of a custom event whenever I add the tooltip dynamically. That way if the event was fired, we switch to `$("body").on("mouseover", .....);` otherwise, we'll use the ordinary `$(".mytooltip").mouseover`.

So something like:

```
    if(...){//Event was fired - i.e. we've added the tooltip dynamically
        $("body").on("mouseover", ".mytooltip", function(){
            mouseOverFunc();
        });
        $("body").on("mouseout", ".mytooltip", function(){
            mouseOutFunc();
        });
    }else{
       $(".mytooltip").mouseover(function(){
            mouseOverFunc();
        });
         $(".mytooltip").mouseout(function(){
            mouseOutFunc();
        });

    }
```

The problem is, I don't know how to detect if an event was fired or not....

PS -- Bonus question: Is what I'm doing reasonable? Or am I overdoing it too much, and should just do `$("body").on("mouseover")` for everything?

Comment: I would be more useful to see how you add the tooltip, as event handlers can be added to the element when you create it

Comment: The tooltip is just markup `<div class='myTooltip' data-width='320'>content goes here</div>`
It's added via an AJAX call - so comes back from the server in the form of a response. I use `.html()` to add the DOM

Comment: Then you can do something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/ySCYs/

Answer (score 0):

If you add the html dynamically you need execute the javascript after the ajax call instead of in the DOM

```
$.ajax{
    //do something
    $(div).html(code);
    if(...){//Event was fired - i.e. we've added the tooltip dynamically
        $("body").on("mouseover", ".mytooltip", function(){
            mouseOverFunc();
        });
        $("body").on("mouseout", ".mytooltip", function(){
            mouseOutFunc();
        });
    }else{
       $(".mytooltip").mouseover(function(){
            mouseOverFunc();
        });
         $(".mytooltip").mouseout(function(){
            mouseOutFunc();
        });
    }
}
```